# Prevent exact duplicates from going into a Mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, duplicates, pymongo

I'm interested in preventing exact duplicates from going into a MongoDB database. I am currently using pymongo to create the database.

for example if I have the current database and I want to enter the following dictionaries:

Current Database:

```
 {'_id': ObjectId('1234'), 'name': 'name1', 'month': '10', 'data': [1,2,3] }
```

Data to enter:

```
my_dict =  { 'name': 'name1', 'month': '10', 'data': [1,2,3] } # should not be entered
my_dict2 = { 'name': 'name2', 'month': '10', 'data': [1,2,3] } # should be entered because name is different 
my_dict3 = { 'name': 'name1', 'month': '11', 'data': [1,2,3] } # should be entered because month is different
my_dict4 = { 'name': 'name1', 'month': '11', 'data': [5,6,7] } # should be entered because month is different
```

So far I have this code but it will prevent a dictionary going in to the database if any of the keys are the same which is not the behavior I need.

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["newdb"]
mycol = mydb["testing"]
mycol.create_index([("name", 1), ("month", 1), ("data", 1)], unique=True)

x = mycol.insert_one(mydict2)
```

Thank you in advance for any help or advice that you can offer!

Comment: Hi, have you try an unique index? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes

Comment: Hi Haniel, thank for the reply. I believe that is what I am doing with the line mycol.create_index([("name", 1), ("month", 1), ("data", 1)], unique=True) Maybe there is functionality possible that I am missing?

Comment: I am so sorry, i miss that. I was looking at the pymongo doc and the direction(s) must be one of (ASCENDING, DESCENDING). `mycol.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("month", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("data", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)` .

Comment: Keep in mind: MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.

Comment: I think the pymongo.ASCENDING part is just for the sort order in which receive the found indexes.

Comment: This is the reference: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=compound%20index#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

Answer (score 0):

Your documents are not exact duplicates because they don't have the `_id` field. You cannot insert *exact duplicates* because only one document can have a particular `_id` in a collection.

Besides using a unique index on content fields, you can also calculate the `_id` value as a hash/digest of the content fields.